# How can I set the private key of the certification in JWT bearer token?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jwt, salesforce

As I questioned before, thanks to the kind man I figured out something. But I am still looking for right solution to the problem that I can't include the private key of the certification I created through openssl rsa in JWT bearer token.

code is something like this.

```
class Salesforce
  def initialize
    @cert_file = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), *%w[server.crt])
    @base_url = "https://test.salesforce.com"
    @auth_endpoint = "/services/oauth2/authorize"
    @token_request_endpoint = "/services/oauth2/token"
    @token_revoke_endpoint = "/services/oauth2/revoke"
    @username = "aben@example.jp"
    @client_id = "3zasdaJhXdjDVZasdaasvasXgO2bCyJriuKHyasfasgqaVxkE7jVKI"
    @private_key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(File.read(@cert_file))  this occurs an error.
   
  end 

  def claim_set
    {
      iss: @client_id,
      sub: @username,
      aud: @base_url,
      exp: (Time.now + 3.minutes).to_i.to_s
    }
  end

  def jwt_bearer_token
    JWT.encode(self.claim_set.to_s, @private_key , 'RS256')
  end

  def request_auth
    post = {grant_type: "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer", assertion: jwt_bearer_token}
    uri = URI.parse("#{@base_url}#{@token_request_endpoint}")
    https = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, 443)
    https.use_ssl = true
    response = https.post(uri.path, post.to_query)
    print response.body


  end
  print Salesforce.new.request_auth
end
```

in server.crt , there is a key looking like this.

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
asdaMIasdasdaIDasmzCCAoMCFCw3alkjsbd;vjabsojAaskjbfvdojsPZO46QOo2uBHE5
MEvzvBYlXMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMIGJdfkjbna;ksljn;fljvsnljjkasdvasasdva
MQsasfasiujbnvoabs@ojvojansoj;dnJBJBBJN+KJNB+b;jb;jnavjsnbfdjb;jasda
bkjbkjbkjBKJBKJBKJBibasdkjbkbKHBKBJBKJBKJBKJBKJBKJBKJVBIVUJHBIKasdva
JABIDVIHVBIAKJBSKJBVIJDKJJKBhvhdkvkakbikhidhvihabidhbaindjansiasdva
bfoaubodfuOkfFZDwejVQ11I3C8IIC
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

and the error says 5:in initialize': Neither PUB key nor PRIV key: not enough data (OpenSSL::PKey::RSAError)

○I wonder if using \n in one-lined certificate can solve this ( I have tried like the one below but it couldnt't solve. maybe I tried in a wrong way and I didn't use ENV because I don't know how to set.)

```
COMPANY_KEY="-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----\nMasdfIasdsfIasdasCzzCasgasdf\nAasdfa2asdfa2z\n-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----"
```

○I wonder if the type of the certificate is right. I found someone who had a certificate looking like this.

```
-----BEGIN RSA CERTIFICATE-----
asdaMIasdasdaIDasmzCCAoMCFCw3alkjsbd;vjabsojAaskjbfvdojsPZO46QOo2uBHE5
MEvzvBYlXMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMIGJdfkjbna;ksljn;fljvsnljjkasdvasasdva
MQsasfasiujbnvoabs@ojvojansoj;dnJBJBBJN+KJNB+b;jb;jnavjsnbfdjb;jasda
bkjbkjbkjBKJBKJBKJBibasdkjbkbKHBKBJBKJBKJBKJBKJBKJBKJVBIVUJHBIKasdva
JABIDVIHVBIAKJBSKJBVIJDKJJKBhvhdkvkakbikhidhvihabidhbaindjansiasdva
bfoaubodfuOkfFZDwejVQ11I3C8IIC
-----END RSA CERTIFICATE-----
```

I have no idea how to fix this. I would really appreciate if you help me.

Thank you .

Comment: As I doubt about my code, the certificate should've been like this '-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
asdaMIasdasd
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----'
I regenerated the RSA Private key and I could solve the error, which means that the certificate I set in Salesforce is wrong so I need to change it though.